# Verify fundamental theorem of Galois for splitting field of $X^4\pm2\in\mathbb {Q}[X]$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field, galois-extensions

My attempt:

Let $f(X) = X^4 − 2$. Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(X)$ over $\mathbb Q$. Now we have factorization:
$$X^4 − 2 = (X^2− \sqrt2)(X^2+ \sqrt2) = (X − \sqrt[4]{2})(X + \sqrt[4]{2})(X −\sqrt[4]{2}i)(X +\sqrt[4]{2}i)$$

Then $K = \mathbb Q[\sqrt[4]{2},i]$

From [here](https://www.isibang.ac.in/%7Estatmath/oldqp/Sol/Algebra%20IV%20MS%20Sol%202013-14.pdf) problem $2(ii)$ then I can show that the Galois group is Dihedral group $D_8$ of $8$ elements.

However,

> 1. The case of $X^4 + 2$ on factorisation goes into $\sqrt i$ which are $\pm {1 \over \sqrt{2}} (1+i)$, and I'm not sure how to deal with that (?)
> 2. If I go case by case for each subgroup of $D_8$, what shows that there cannot be any other intermediate fields? How exactly do I "verify" the fundamental theorem?

Comment: Note that all subgroups of $D_8$ are known. On the other side, we also have all subfields. Then you just compare both sides. Is there a bijection?

Comment: Concerning 1, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143919/galois-group-of-x4-2-over-mathbbq/1144004).

Comment: @AbhigyanSaha Some write the symmetry group of the regular $n$-gon as $D_n$ (since it acts on $n$ vertices), but others write it as $D_{2n}$ (since it has $2n$ elements). I'd write the group in question here as $D_4$.