# Basis for splitting field of degree 8

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory

Problem: Find a basis of splitting field of splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ for $f=X^4+2$.

My attempt: Note $X^4+2$ has $4$ roots, $\sqrt[4]{2} \epsilon i, \sqrt[4]{2}\epsilon$ ,$\sqrt[4]{2} \epsilon i^2$, $\sqrt[4]{2}\epsilon i^4$, where $\epsilon = e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}$. Therefore,

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}\epsilon,i)$ is a splitting field extension for $f=X^4+2$. But,

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}\epsilon,i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{8},i)$ Hence,

$1,\sqrt[4]{8},\sqrt[4]{8}^2,\sqrt[4]{8}^3$, $i$ , $\sqrt[4]{8i}$, $i\sqrt[4]{8}^2$,$i\sqrt[4]{8}^3$ is a basis for the splitting field extension above.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Correct,also you can write as $1,\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[4]{4},\sqrt[4]{8}$.

Comment: Title: the degree is [eight](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143919/galois-group-of-x4-2-over-mathbbq) and not four. We have $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2},i):\Bbb Q]=8$.